# Social framework auto-appending access key

Tags: ios, facebook, access-token

I am attempting to retrieve a list of friends with specific fields using the iOS 6 Social Framework.  I am using the URL:

```
NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fbUserID"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/friends?fields=id,name,picture", username];
    NSURL *friendsList = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

But the framework seems to be appending the access key to it automagically, and is doing so with a '?' as if it were the first URL parameter. What's more, the API is complaining that it was expecting the end of the statement and not a ?, as is evident in this error:

```
error =     {
        code = 2500;
        message = "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"?\".\" at character 15: id,name,picture?access_token=HHyDtnfrjnojngehrtjgnekngeXsI0ZBansnfjDHDhljoQKIfZB5i3JMUHlJIm5HHdwM4s5ixyu38es1vj9XXTcLSS6ZCOi13zQW87dw9YP3DgpllDz5KB6WnSeYGxS9RMfd3npZBwZAEUdmkJHoYlWvflfcQHVwIydLfExjOaNpGZBGhYvb3XlrZAXt7jmDai6FiMoZBRmdOUWfA5vubeNbvvn9y80cPaUPZBZCAZDZD";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

Is this normal behavior for the framework? Is the access token usually appended in this manner? If so, how should I form my urlString so that this is not a problem?

Comment: How are you actually making the call with the url you create? Are you using SLRequest?

Comment: Hi Ming Li, thanks for the response!!  Yes, I am using an SLRequest to send the URL. I am trying to do everything within iOS's Social.Framework and not implement the FB SDK at all. Do you have any recommendations or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the "fields" param in the NSURL, try creating just a plain NSURL

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/friends", username];
NSURL *friendsList = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

And call requestForServiceType:requestMethod:URL:parameters, and pass in something like:

```
@{@"fields": @"id,name,picture"}
```

for the "parameters" field.